# RMI/Proxy in ceylon and relation to non-default methods

Tags: proxy, rmi, ceylon

I want to write an RMI library in/for Ceylon (since I have not found one so far).

The first thing I need is a proxy. In Java I used something like

```
Proxy.newProxyInstance(classLoader, interfaces, handler);
```

**1.** Is there something equivalent in Ceylon? (haven't found something)

---

Attempting to write something like this my own, I came across this [solution for the JVM](http://github.com/ceylon/ceylon/blob/6321bbb0602dc8857621a3e18defe7ede536cc93/compiler-java/test/src/com/redhat/ceylon/compiler/java/test/issues/bug71xx/bug7105/run.ceylon) using byte code manipulation. 
Nifty and exactly what I want.

Notice, that this can even produce a proxy for a class, not only for interface like in Java. In Ceylon this is should be legit, since there are no fields and we can simulate the whole class with method calls.

**2.** If creating proxies for classes is a no-go just tell me.
Also, what is the Ceylon intuition/future about proxies? Shall there be (no) proxies?

---

In a future with proxies we have one major problem:

In Ceylon we have the `default` keyword, without it a method can not be refined/overwritten. This also results in `final` methods for the compiled Java output classes. Thereby (not even) the byte code manipulation can overwrite those and redirect them to an invocation handler/interceptor.

**3.** How do we deal with this?

---

I assume not at all? I totally get the idea of disallowing the refinement of methods and the `default`/`final` keywords, but this obstructs RMI/proxies for classes.

**4.** Are proxies for classes a bad idea?

---

And yes, there are so much more questions I am currently thinking about and investigating on: JS implementation, interfaces and default methods, etc

These points seem to be the most relevant at the moment, so let's start here.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this module I wrote:

https://github.com/gavinking/ceylon.proxy

Alternatively, if you're only targeting the JVM, you could just use Java's `Proxy` directly.

Answer (score 1):

During further research I found:

**1.** Proxies are currently part of the Ceylon 1.4 milestone (issues regarding proxies).

**3.** Enabling EE mode for the ceylon compiler, removes the `final` keyword.

From this point on the solution I found works like intended and is exactly the same as the one provided by Gavin.